# Event is passed as `undefined` while using <ButtonGroup> of react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I was using plain HTML for using `select` tag of html. Now, I'm trying to replace the HTML part by `react-bootstrap`. I have every thing similar except `react-bootstrap` tags but, I am getting undefined whenever I'm using `<ButtonGroup>` of `react-bootstrap` instead of `select` tag of plain HTML.
This is working:

```
  <select onChange={this.groupBySelector}>
    <option value="invoice">GROUP BY INVOICE</option>
    <option value="customer">GROUP BY CUSTOMER</option>
    <option value="month">GROUP BY MONTH</option>
  </select>
```

This is not working:

```
  <ButtonGroup>
    <DropdownButton title="GROUP BY" id="bg-nested-dropdown" onSelect={this.groupBySelector}>
      <MenuItem value="invoice">GROUP BY INVOICE</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="customer">GROUP BY CUSTOMER</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="month">GROUP BY MONTH</MenuItem>
    </DropdownButton>
  </ButtonGroup>
```

`groupBySelector` function is as follows:

```
groupBySelector(event){
    console.log(event);
    if ((event.target.value)==="invoice"){
      this.setState({invoiceType:'invoice'})
    } else if ((event.target.value)==="customer") {
      this.setState({invoiceType:'customer'})
    } else if ((event.target.value)==="month") {
      this.setState({invoiceType:'month'})
    } else {
      this.setState({invoiceType:'invoice'})
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `react-bootstrap`'s docs, the `onSelect` event for `DropdownButton` does not return an event (just like `select`).

Instead, you need to attribute an `eventKey` to each `MenuItem` component.

```
  groupBySelector(eventOrKey){
    this.setState({
      invoiceType: eventOrKey.target ? eventOrKey.target.value : eventOrKey
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DropdownButton title="GROUP BY" id="bg-nested-dropdown" onSelect={this.groupBySelector}>
        <MenuItem eventKey="invoice">GROUP BY INVOICE</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="customer">GROUP BY CUSTOMER</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="month">GROUP BY MONTH</MenuItem>
      </DropdownButton>
    )
  }
```

If you want to bind the event through arrow function (although not recommended):

```
render() {
  return (
    <DropdownButton title="GROUP BY" id="bg-nested-dropdown" onSelect={eventKey => this.setState({ invoiceType: eventKey })}>
      <MenuItem eventKey="invoice">GROUP BY INVOICE</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="customer">GROUP BY CUSTOMER</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="month">GROUP BY MONTH</MenuItem>
    </DropdownButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: doing `  onDropdownSelect = (eventKey) => {
    this.setState({invoiceType: eventKey})
  }` works! pls update ur answer

Comment: @noobie I though you needed `groupBySelector` event. Also, I don't recommend using arrow function in this case due to performance issues. Every time you component renders, the `onSelect` event handler gets a new instance :)

Comment: are you following [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html) link?

Comment: Yes, this is the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use arrow function to add event:

```
<DropdownButton title="GROUP BY" id="bg-nested-dropdown" onSelect={(eventKey, event) => this.groupBySelector(event)}>...
```

Comment: Try to add an eventKey to MenuItem